# React with Redux: error on propType property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new in the React world. I got a course to training React and Redux.
Like yesterday I got an error while I'm attending an online training
Even though, I walk through the author course and copy the code from the screen I get an error:

Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `courses` was not specified in `CoursesPage`. Check the render method of `Connect(CoursesPage)`.

I have uploaded my code to github: https://github.com/tarcisiocorte/reactredux/blob/master/src/components/course/CoursesPage.js

again....I will appreciate some help.

```html
import React, {PropTypes} from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as courseActions from '../../actions/courseActions';

class CoursesPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      course:{title: ""}
    };

    this.onTitleChange = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
    this.onClickSave = this.onClickSave.bind(this);
  }


  onTitleChange(event){
    const course = this.state.course;
    course.title = event.target.value;
    this.setState({course: course});
  }

  courseRow(course, index){
      return <div key={index}>{course.title}</div>;
  }

    onClickSave() {
        this.props.dispatch(courseActions.createCourse(this.state.course));
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Courses</h1>
          {this.props.courses.map(this.courseRow)}
        <h1>Add Courses</h1>
        <input
            type="text"
            onChange={this.onTitleChange}
            value={this.state.course.title} />

          <input
              type="submit"
              value="Save"
              onClick={this.onClickSave} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CoursesPage.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return{
        courses: state.courses
    };
}

export  default connect(mapStateToProps)(CoursesPage);
```

Comment: Can you please share the relevent code snippet here?

Answer (score 2):

In https://github.com/tarcisiocorte/reactredux/blob/master/src/index.js#L11

You need to specify a default for courses.

You have specified that your `courses` prop is required:

```
courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired
```

so you need to pass in something from the redux store and by the looks of it the `courses` property in your redux store is `undefined`. (Put a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/tarcisiocorte/reactredux/blob/master/src/components/course/CoursesPage.js#L59) to check that is actually the case)

You can either make sure your redux store always returns something for your `courses` or your can remove the `isRequired` constrain:

```
CoursesPage.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    courses: PropTypes.array
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your 'Routes' component, you'll want to change

```
<Route path="courses" component={CoursesPage} />
```

to

```
<Route path='courses' render={(stuff) => (
  <CoursePage courses={stuff} />
)}/>
```

When you use component, you can't add your required props, so render would be a good alternative.  This also means you'll have to add redux connections to your routes.js since you need to get that information from somewhere.

Another, more simpler, solution would be just to eliminate courses as a prop and get that information directly from redux when CoursePage loads up.  You've already done half the battle with your mapStateToProps, therefore you dont need to have it with the "isRequired" in your propTypes.  This is basically when Klugjo said, so if you decide to take this approach, give him credit.

I'd also hazard a guess that if 'courses' in your store doesn't exist, your isRequired is being triggered as well.  So you might be able to keep isRequired as long as you have your data for that prop in the store.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across a similar failed prop type error, such as below, or if the other answers did not resolve your issue, the following might be an alternate fix for you. In the context of `user428745`'s post above, `someProjects` and `ResponsiblePage` in the error below would correspond to the `courses` prop (some array of values) and the `CoursesPage` component, respectively. 
[image: prop type validation error]

Given `user428745`'s setup below

```
CoursesPage.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    courses: state.courses
  };
}
```

The issue might be related to how the redux state gets the `state.courses` value in the first place. In my case, the prop (ie. `courses` as in `state.courses`) in `mapStateToProps` was being set before the data was available from the redux store. This happened due to an API data call that had not yet finished. My fix was:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    courses: state.courses || [] // Equivalent to statement below
    //courses: state.courses == null ? [] : state.courses
  };
}
```

If `state.courses` is null (due to API data not loaded yet) we return `[]` to satisfy the `array` requirement on our prop. If it is valid, which means the data was available and was put inside of `state.courses`, then we simply return `state.courses` similar to before.

Note also that there might be different required configuration setups (to make redux work properly), ie. depending on how you link your reducer(s) to your root reducer (which would be the content in `index.js` inside of `reducers` folder). If the error is still not fixed with these changes, try another approach with the root reducer, such as:

```
// From this (see `user428745`'s source files, where 'courseReducer' was imported as 'courses')
export default combineReducers({
  courseReducer
});

// To this
export default combineReducers({
  rootReducer: courseReducer
});

// Where 'mapStateToProps' would also have to change
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    courses: state.rootReducer.courses || []
  };
}
```

And where you intend to use this value, ie. with `this.props.courses` or `props.courses` in your `CoursesPage` setup, you could console log the values (or whatever you wanted to do) only when the array is not empty:

```
if (props.courses.length > 0) {
  console.log(props.courses);
}
```

Or maybe listen to `props.courses` changes so that you perform *something* only "in the moment" after it changes (whereas the `if` statement above would be valid at all times, from when the prop was filled with values):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.courses.length > 0) {
    console.log(props.courses);
  }
}, [props.courses]);
```

Note that if you use `useEffect`, make sure it is within your `CoursesPage` component, and not in the "root" of the file where you would ie. write `export default CoursesPage`.